# Will spring Boot datasource properties work if we configure datasource programmatically in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, connection, datasource

Will Spring Boot datasource properties work if we configure datasource programmatically?

The following properties worked only when I fetch DB configuration from application.properties. If I configure datasource programmatically the following properties are not working.

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
```

I used the following code to configure datasource programmatically

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(userName).password(password).url(url).driverClassName(driverName)
            .build();
}
```

To make it work programmatically I used the following code snippet.But I'm not convinced. I feel it is not a cleaner solution. I have to read at least 20 properties from application.properties and add it to PoolProperties.

```
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
        poolProperties.setUrl(url);
        poolProperties.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        poolProperties.setUsername(userName);
        poolProperties.setPassword(password);
        poolProperties.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        poolProperties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolProperties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        poolProperties.setTestOnReturn(false);
        poolProperties.setValidationInterval(30000);
        poolProperties.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        poolProperties.setInitialSize(10);
        poolProperties.setMaxActive(10);
        poolProperties.setMaxIdle(5);
        poolProperties.setMinIdle(5);
        poolProperties.setMaxWait(10000);
        poolProperties.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        poolProperties.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        poolProperties.setLogAbandoned(true);
        poolProperties.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        DataSource datasource = new DataSource(); // import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
        datasource.setPoolProperties(poolProperties);
        return datasource;
    }
```

It there way we can make the following default Spring Boot properties work?

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
```

Comment: You are already using a supported datasource why are you configuring it manually? All the properties you set are configurable, what do you gain by adding the programmatic configuration? If you really want you need to specify the proper prefix `spring.datasource.tomcat` in your case. But as stated from what you posted here you gain nothing by adding it programmatically.

Comment: Actually I’m fetching database password from Hashicorp Vault that is the reason I’m configuring it manually. When I do it programmatically initial size, max active, max idle, min idle.... settings on application.properties is not working. How to make it work?

Comment: Make the vault properties part of the regular proces instead of doing manual configuration. Write an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which registers a Vault based `PropertySource` and adds it to the list of `PropertySource`s . That way you can use all the features Spring Boot gives you.

Comment: I will try ApplicationContextInitializer and update you. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: This was really a pain for me too

Answer (score 0):

remember to give tomcat from properties for db in property files like this.

```
# Oracle DB - "foo"
spring.datasource.tomcat.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db-server-foo:1521/FOO
spring.datasource.tomcat.username=fooadmin
spring.datasource.tomcat.password=foo123
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
```

then configure datasource like this.

```
 /**
 * Auto-configured DataSource
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.tomcat")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: I get my DB password from Vault and not from the properties file. I didn't get a simple example for ApplicationContextInitializer with Vault.

Comment: You can get that value alone first, and then set password alone as u did in your first code. You were telling that first code of programmatically doing was not working as you didn't give tomcat in @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.tomcat")

Comment: Facing the same issue with HikariDatasource ... and exactly @ThiagarajanRamanathan mentions ... I also take the password from AWS Secret Manager so have to have dynamic and property file based datasource configuration at the same time. Any help will be much appreciated.